# How can I turn values into an array using Python/NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

The exercise consists in organizing values from 0-5 in an array, using NumPy, and those values were originally from a 3x3 matrix.

Example:

```
[[1 1 3]
 [4 5 2]
 [3 0 0]]
```

This is I wanted the output to come out:

```
[2,2,1,2,1,1]
```

I tried using np.array() and np.asarry(), but it didn't work. Moreover, I thought of using flatten() function, yet it didn't suit my goal.

What I tried:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.matrix([[1,1,3], [4,5,2], [3,0,0]]) # Primary matrix, used for obtaining the values
print("Original Matrix: ") # Print original matrix
print(m)

print("Occurrences: ")
for i in range(6):
  occur = (np.count_nonzero(m == i)) # Count the number of elements satisfying the condition
  print(i, ":", occur)
```

My output:

```
Occurrences:
0 : 2
1 : 2
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 1
5 : 1
```

Comment: @Mark, you should make that an answer so it can be marked as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done this way:

```
# declare matrix:
mat = np.matrix([[1, 1, 3], 
 [4, 5, 2],
 [3, 0, 0]])

# get flattened array:
arr = mat.getA1()

# get the bincounts:
bc = np.bincount(arr)
```

This would give you the same result

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It worked. However, I still can't understand how they count the occurences. If you could explain to me.

Comment: Try reading the documentation for `np.bincount`, heres a summary:
`Count number of occurrences of each value in array of non-negative ints.`
Basically you're just binning the values here, just like you would for plotting

Comment: Now it's more clear, thanks;)

Comment: You might also wanna look into `np.digitize` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) for other values. Please accept my answer if it solved your issue, thanks!